my pocket tester flickers red when first making contact then turns green
I was using my Klien pocket tester to see if any of the wires in my outlet box have power. I used the tester on outlet and had the tester light up red signifying I had power there. But when I moved to the switch box to check power, I only got a very random flicker of the red light quickly changing to green. So no power but curious about the color flicker.

How close to the actual wires was the tester?

One needs not only the correct tools, but to learn how the tool woks. Some "detectors" are very high impedance, and indicate any EMF, even that picked up by being in proximity to another wire.

This is where using other tester types is good to double check.  Might just be phantom voltage from another close by circuit.  Those testers are good for do not touch reading.
